# QGraphics Scene Rect is growing

Tags: c++, qt

So I am trying to move a rectangle across the scene, and redrawing the scene at every timeout. Everything seems to be fine except that the rectangles keep growing...and I can't figure out why. I am moving them by i in the x coordinate, and moving all the x coordinates by i, so there should be no growing horizontally.

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    timelineScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsViewTimeline->setScene(timelineScene);
    ui->graphicsViewTimeline->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    t = new QTimer(this);
    t->setInterval(100);
    connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){timelineAdvance();});

    connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){i++;});
    t->start();
    i = 10;

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::timelineAdvance()
{
    timelineScene->clear();


    timelineScene->addRect(5,7,1200, 85, QPen(Qt::white), QBrush(QColor(Qt::black))); 
    timelineScene->addLine(5,93,5,100, QPen(Qt::white, 3)); /** Time = Now **/
    timelineScene->addLine(305,93,305,100, QPen(Qt::white, 3)); /** Time = 300s from now **/
    timelineScene->addLine(605,93,605,100, QPen(Qt::white, 3)); /** Time = 600s from now **/
    timelineScene->addLine(905,93,905,100, QPen(Qt::white, 3)); /** Time = 900s from now **/

    timelineScene->addRect(i, 10,i+50, 80, QPen(Qt::red, 3), QBrush(QColor(38, 38, 38)));
    timelineScene->addRect(i+120, 10, i+150, 80, QPen(Qt::blue, 3), QBrush(QColor(38, 38, 38)));

}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDateTime> 
#include <stdlib.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    int i;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    void timelineAdvance();
    QGraphicsScene *timelineScene;
    QTimer *t;
};
```

I do not see anything that should make the rectangles stretch over time, does anyone have any ideas why it is doing it?

Comment: Are you aware about the doc. [QGraphicsScene::sceneRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop)?: _(i.e., a rectangle that grows when items are added to or moved in the scene, but never shrinks)._

Comment: @Scheff I did indeed add that, it did not affect the rectangles strange growth

Comment: _I did indeed add that_ That means, you added `timeLineScene->setSceneRect(QRectF());` e.g. before or after `timeLineScene->clear();` (in `MainWindow::timelineAdvance()`), and this didn't change anything?

Comment: Maybe, I misunderstood your issue. Is it about `timelineScene->addRect(i, 10,i+50, 80, ...);` (and the following line)? So, the 3rd parameter of `addRect()` is _width_ (in opposition to right border). As it depends of `i` (which is increased over time if I got it right), that makes the rectangle growing in fact.

Comment: I had timeLineScene->setSceneRect(QRectF()); in the constructor. OK, so that makes sense, I thought it was (x1,y1,x2,y2). Thanks so much, that was it!